# Samsung galaxy s5 sm-g901f v5.0.2 Move an app from user to system

Tags: samsung, system

I have a samsung galaxy s5 sm-g901f android: 5.0.2 (I live in france) and I would like to move an user app to a system app. I already dowload system app mover and do the read and write mount but it still doesn't word. I also root my device. And I try to move de file manually but the app does not work anymore. What can I do? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple steps, but you might have forgotten to do the last step.

1. Uninstall the user app as usual, but keep its APK somewhere. Rebooting after this is recommended.
2. Depending on whether it needs system privilege, put the APK into either `/system/app` or `/system/priv-app`
3. Set permissions for APK to `rw-r--r--` (0644) and reboot.

Rather curious about what you're trying to achieve by moving the app to system - is it necessary?

Comment: Thank you I do everything you explain and the app become a system app but I would like to do this to cheat at pokemon go with the app lockito and the game see that I activate fictional position so though that create a system app would show to pokemon go the false location. If you have an idea?...

Comment: ----------------------------------Whit correction from the other message----------------Thank you I do everything you explain and the app become a system app but I would like to do this to cheat at pokemon go with the app lockito but the game see that I activate fictional position so I though that create a system app would show to pokemon go the false location, but it don't work. I go where I set the location before but pokemon go see that it's not the real GPS. If you have an idea?...

Comment: For that you would want to try other location-faking apps (and many of them are Xposed modules). Moving the app to system does no help in masking faked location.